# How to handle click event in mouse and keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done

1. some  html tags click event it's working by mouse click  and
   keyboard enter
2. some  html tags click events are are not working when
   press in keyboard enter.   only working mouse click.

I need both are we excutue in single method

> like: Button, Anchor

"**Button **and**  Anchor**" - tags only suporting .

"**p,div,span,h1**"- tags are not suporting .

> Button and Anchor Tag only working both mouse click and keyboard enter
>   !
>
> remaining element are not working tab using keyboard enter  why ?

**dont't say keycode method for keyboard enter i need similar button and anchor tag**

Here is the  demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was p.");
    });
  
  $("div").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was div.");
    });
  
  $("span").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was span.");
    });
  
  $("h1").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was h1.");
    });
  
  $("button").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was button.");
    });
  
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was a.");
    });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Button and Anchor Tag only working both mouse click and keyboard enter ! </h2>
<h2>remaining element are not working tab using keyboard enter ? </h2>
<br>

<br>
<p tabindex="0">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<div tabindex="0">Click on this div.</div>
<span tabindex="0">Click on this span.</span>
<h1 tabindex="0">Click on this h1.</h1>
<button> Click on this button.</button> <br>
<a href="#"> Click on this anchor </a>
```

Thanks
J.Jayaprakash

Comment: May be this link can be of help 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`keypress` event](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

> To determine which character was entered, examine the event object that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code.

```js
function alertTag( tag ){
  alert("The element was " + $(tag).prop("tagName"));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p, div, span, h1, button, a").click(function(e) {
    alertTag(e.target);
  }).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // optionally
      alertTag(e.target);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p tabindex="0">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<div tabindex="0">Click on this div.</div>
<span tabindex="0">Click on this span.</span>
<h1 tabindex="0">Click on this h1.</h1>
<button> Click on this button.</button> <br>
<a href="#"> Click on this anchor </a>
```

If you want to use the same method for all the elements (while I don't see the point in doing so) you need to include `e.preventDefault()`. Otherwise, when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> you will trigger both the `click` and the `keypress` events.

An alternative could be to force the `p`, `div`, `span` and `h1` elements to trigger a `click` event when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on them:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p, div, span, h1, button, a").click(function(e) {
    alert("The element was " + $(e.target).prop("tagName"));
  });
  
  $("p, div, span, h1").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $(e.target).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p tabindex="0">Click on this paragraph.</p>
<div tabindex="0">Click on this div.</div>
<span tabindex="0">Click on this span.</span>
<h1 tabindex="0">Click on this h1.</h1>
<button> Click on this button.</button> <br>
<a href="#"> Click on this anchor </a>
```

If you really want to do it for **all** the HTML tags (even when I think that's not a good idea) you can do the following.

```
$("body *").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $(e.target).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Then, all the elements will react to a <kbd>enter</kbd> like they do to a click. But you should really try to replace `body *` for a selector that covers just the elements that you want. For example, you can add the class `.enterTriggersClick` to the target elements and then do:

```
$(".enterTriggersClick").keypress(function(e) { ...
```

Comment: i need to write only one method to execute similar button and anchor

Comment: Thanks  David... recenly i found  some tags are working both mouse click and keyboard enter it's only supoorting Button and A tags only.  i need similar approach for div and span ...

Comment: u can see my question  code snipt  i am not write any  condition when keypress  if (e.which == 13) {}  Button and A tag only working u can  press tab button in your keyboard when focus on the button u can click the enter it will be  work

Comment: Just `<a>` and `<button>` support what you want. You can't do it in a `<span>` or a `<div>`. The only way is to emulate it with `keypress` or similar.

Comment: i need same ways the all HTML Tags.  my question is understand ? 

Thanks 
David.

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Note that you need the condition `e.which == 13` because in JavaScript there is no event `enterPress`. Just anchors and buttons implement it. Emulation in other elements is the best you will get.